# Getting an iif and statement to work in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have written the following statement but have not been able to get it to work.  Can anyone help me?

```
=iif(Fields!Requirement_Description.Value="4. Transport Req. Mon PM" and Fields!Transport_Requirement_Y_N.Value=TRUE,"Yes","No")
```

Many thanks :)

[image]

Comment: What is the data type for Transport_Requirement_Y_N? What happens if you change the `=TRUE` to `=1`? The syntax seems fine, it works for me on a test report, so that is all I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

=IFF((Fields!Requirement_Description.Value="4. Transport Req. Mon PM") AND (Fields!Transport_Requirement_Y_N.Value=TRUE), "Yes","No")